# Adding button (type:Image) in grid view and make the image visible only if the count is more than 0 for that column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have N rows and 9 columns in which two columns will be visible only after clicking on the image. But for each row I want the image to be visible only if there is text in that columns. Please help me.

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" Visible="False" 
SortExpression="Notes" /> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" Visible="False" 
SortExpression="Notes" /> 
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/Imgs.jpg" 
Text="Button" /> 



 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = true; 
GridView1.Columns[3].Visible = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in RowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var item = (MyType)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("MyButton");
            if (item.Children.Count == 0)
                button.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nima I tried it. I got error. Here is the error message...'MyType' does not contain a definition for 'Children' and no extension method 'Children' accepting a first argument of type 'MyType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi @user2356985,  You must replace MyType with the type of objects bound to each row. RowDataBound is run for each row, so you can put the logic of displaying or hiding controls here. (This code was just a sample)